# If row contains text add blank row above. If row is blank then do nothing

Tags: google-sheets

I know it's probably a `vlookup` that can accomplish this or something but I'm just not sure how to phrase it. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm trying to create a todo list with the dates in reverse chronological order (ie from most recent to least). This means we add events at the top row. I'm wondering if theres a way to detect if the row has text and add a blank row for the next text instead of having to manually add a row each time.

I'll attach a pic. I'm looking to add a blank row above row 2 if row two has any text at all.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: You have to use a script and on edit or on change trigger. Please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

Comment: Welcome. @Rubén asked you to show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts. This helps us understand your scenario and what kind of solution you would accept. Your question implies that you are looking for an automated solution but you don't explain your rationale; perhaps you have formula that you want to duplicate. OTOH, have you considered using a keybord shortcut to insert a new blank row? Or sort the to-do list on "Target Date" and manually update the list periodically? It's hard to suggest a specific answer without more information from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script helped me. All credit to original posters.

The [autoInsertRowAtTopOfSheet_](https://notifications.google.com/g/p/AD-FnEwMfSqtGrmNZrOf-rDWnVa4GV6FzyYRvrlYAHvrQNTIqjKtQSTUiADLjYcF8okyFTkKCVEl90nCDXfa-tvLhpQyzOiN_Wfr9DWzzwKyvzwdKHB9nK564KGSAkp1TRz74X8) script will insert a row below the frozen section in the sheet when a cell in column A in the first data row is edited. So try editing cell A2 and see what happens.

Comment: Links to external resources are OK, but the Help Centre also demands "[Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).